# How to parameterize the SOAP endpoint in Jenkins for multiple environments

Tags: soap, jenkins-cli, parasoft

I have a task to run the soap .tst file on multiple environments on Jenkins. But the problem is every time I have to make the respective env to active and run it in Jenkins. Is there a way to parameterize the multiple environments.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are using soatestcli in Jenkins, so your command line may looks like bellow:

```
soatestcli.exe -config <configuration name> -resource <path to test suite name.tst relative to the workspace> -environment "My_QA_ENV"
```

> -environment

allows to set active environment in command line

You can have another options to change and manage your environment.
Use .envs file. See Parasoft SOAtest User's Guide > Functional/Integration Testing > End-to-End Test Scenarios > Referencing Environments
With .envs files you can modify the configurations from single location.